# How can I select an element in a web page developed with Ext JS

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

```
<a id="createDetailItem" class="x-btn x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-icon-text-left x-btn-icon-text-left x-btn-default-toolbar-small-icon-text-left" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" tabindex="0" style="right: auto; left: 772px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;">
<span id="createDetailItem-btnWrap" class="x-btn-wrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
<span id="createDetailItem-btnEl" class="x-btn-button" role="presentation">
<span id="createDetailItem-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on">New Expense Item</span>
<span id="createDetailItem-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon-el icon-plus " role="presentation" unselectable="on" style=""/>
</span>
</span>
</a>
```

Tried

By.XPath("//a[contains(@class, 'createDetailItem') and contains(@class, 'x-btn-wrap')]"
By.CssSelector("a[class='x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center']"

By.XPath("//a[contains(@class, 'x-btn-wrap') and contains(@class, 'x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center')]"
And many more.

Can you help in selecting the New Expense Item Button. Thanks

Comment: Please try this xpath :- //a[contains(@ID,'createDetailItem')]//span[text()='New Expense Item']

Comment: Still no joy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please share what error you are getting

Comment: or try this //a[contains(@ID,'createDetailItem')]/span/span//span[text()='New Expense Item'] . if possible please  share ur url ?

Comment: NoSuchElementException was unhandle in the user code.

Comment: can u share ur url ?

Comment: An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.Support.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Could not find element by: By.XPath: //a[contains(@ID,'createDetailItem')/span/span//span[text()='New Expense item']

Comment: Its a company UAT site, if you let me have your details I can send directly to you.

Comment: ankursingh.creative@gmail.com use this @SamOba

Answer (score 0):

Why using locator xpath when you have id:

```
By.Id("createDetailItem-btnInnerEl")
```